# Use project context in nuget package

Tags: .net-core, package, nuget, post-build-event

I have two project A and B.

A project is a nuget package.

B is project what have installed nuget package A.

What I want is use post build event from project A in context of project B.
It is mean that, I want use macros like $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName) in post build command of project A. For example post build event of project A:

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll v1" />
  </Target>
```

Currently outputPath and assemblyName are taken from context of project A. So this package is not even build with successfully, because there occurs error `"The command "dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\SwaggerConfigurator.dll v1" exited with code -2147450733."`. So this post build event should be fire only when project B is building and in project B context.

Can anyone give some advice or tips how to do that?
Or maybe there is some walkaround, how to run this command after build of project B but not including it in project B?